# PDAL filters reprojection is not changing Z values

Tags: coordinate-system, las, pdal, vertical-transformation

I'm trying to reproject an LAS file using PDAL, and it looks like the X/Y values are being transformed, but the Z values are staying the same.

```
pdal translate input.las output.las -f filters.reprojection --filters.reprojection.in_srs="EPSG:32615" --filters.reprojection.out_srs="EPSG:8771"
```

The input LAS file is in UTM 15N using WGS84 as the datum and the altitudes should be ellipsoid heights in meters.

After reprojecting the X/Y values have been transformed, but the Z values are still the same, and since the output projection is supposed to be a NAD83 projection for Oklahoma with NAVD88 as the vertical datum both with units of US survey feet the height data looks squashed.

Are there settings that I am missing to force the use of vertical datum reprojections?

Answer (score 5):

UTM 15N EPSG:32615 doesn't technically have a vertical datum, so to do a vertical transformation a vertical datum has to be specified. I changed the input SRS to `--filters.reprojection.in_srs="EPSG:32615+5703"` which specifies the vertical datum as NAVD88 in meters.

The output SRS EPSG:8771 includes a vertical datum of NAVD88 in ft, so an additional vertical datum is not required.

I'm not entirely sure if 5703 is the vertical datum that I want to use if the original altitude was in WGS84 ellipsoid height in meters, but specifying the vertical datum in the input SRS was what I was missing.

**Edit:**
I changed my input SRS to `--filters.reprojection.in_srs="+init=epsg:32615 +geoidgrids=C:\vdatum_GEOID12A\vdatum\core\geoid12a\g2012au7.gtx"` and I had to download an appropriate `gtx` file for the area I was reprojecting, and if I'm understanding this correctly the geoidgrids from the geoid12a series convert from ellipsoidal altitude in NAD83 (practically the same as WGS84) to NAVD88 in meters. Now that the input has a well defined vertical datum, the reprojection to EPSG:8771 works as expected.

Comment: Try 4326 as vertical datum as in https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2018/05/use-pdal-to-apply-vertical-datum-geoid.html.

Comment: @user30184 4326 isn't a vertical datum. If I use that I get an error "SetCompoundCS() fails, vertical component is not VERT_CS

Comment: Understandable. It seems that `"EPSG:32610+4326"` worked in 2018 but maybe PDAL is fixed since that.